# Adding extra field in JSON in backend code

Tags: javascript, java, json, rest, api

I was planning to add an extra field in the Json response from the backend.
Since this API is consumed by a lot of Clients, i will not be able to change every client.
Will this effect the existing front end client functionality.

Comment: I don't think it will affect existing clients if you add an additional field, since they will still be getting all the data they require.

Comment: Depends on how you parse JSON in those clients.

Comment: It should not as long as you send the response in correct format. Also Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and MCVE. How do you expect us to help you fix your problem if you don't show us any code?

Answer (score 2):

> Will this impact existing clients?

We can't know without auditing all the clients.

> Should this impact existing clients?

No, it *shouldn't*, but...

> Could this impact existing clients?

Yes. Some clients may enumerate the fields in the JSON document (more common for RPC-style APIs, meta programming, or reflection). They may or may not break outright, but in this case the results are unspecified.

> So what do I do?

There are two options:

1. Adding a new field *should* be safe. You apply minimal effort based on the expectation that overall risk is low and just add the field. (IMO this is the pragmatic option.)
2. You create a new API that adds the field, either /v2/ or some other endpoint that has the extra field so new clients can opt-in to the new data and old clients are unaffected. (This is the bullet-proof option.)

You can also make the new fields opt-in if the client passes certain headers in the request so people can test their clients for compatibility before the new API is released (basically #2, but temporary).

Which solution is appropriate depends on the nature and number of your API clients. For example if you have a large number of clients in embedded devices, you should probably not change the existing API. OTOH if your clients all use a common library to interact with your API and can update easily, you can update the client library first and then update the API after the majority of your clients have updated.

> Can I make this easier going forward?

Yes, if you have an API contract / design document that states that "clients should expect that new fields may be added to existing endpoints" then this essentially becomes a safe operation all the time.

It's good to consider what your overall stance is towards backwards compatibility, deprecation, and upgrades. Going forward you should write this down so both you and your clients have the same expectations about how your API will evolve. This way you can refer to the design document to make this decision, and client authors can refer to it to make appropriate programming decisions.